# How can I test long-running, time-based applications?

Tags: testing, timer

I have a Linux application that performs periodic tasks on behalf of the user.  Think `cron` though the actions taken by the application are quite different, the scheduling is somewhat similar.  I'd like to do some black-box testing of very long runs (the period maxes out at 35 days).  I'd prefer not to do the tests in real time for obvious reasons.  I could just manually advance the clock.  Or I could set up a fake private NTP server that ran its clock at some multiple of wall clock time (an hour a minute, or something) and fooled the system that the application is running on into advancing its clock quickly, too.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Fake NTP is my option but better suggestion is to replace your own "cron" kind of functionality with well tested libraries (for e.g. Quartz if you are on Java platform) and avoid this testing itself.

Comment: I'm less concerned with whether the event happens every period than with things like memory growth that come out of the periodic processing.  Relying on an outside scheduler doesn't help me with that.  Though this does suggest an interesting idea.  I have several processes that need to do things periodically or at certain times.  I could have a central time keeper that send SIG_TBD to the process when it is the next time to do something.  (Alas, that breaks down when a single process has several timers.)